# Run gradle spock test task in parallel

Tags: testing, gradle, parallel-processing, spock

In my `build.gradle` I have the following test task

```
task test1(type: Test) {
    ignoreFailures true
    testLogging {
        events 'started', 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed'
        exceptionFormat "full"
        showStandardStreams = true

        afterSuite { desc, result ->
            if (!desc.parent) { // will match the outermost suite
                failedTest += result.failedTestCount
            }
        }
    }
    include "org/company/project/test/Test1.class"
}

task test2(type: Test) {
    ignoreFailures true
    testLogging {
        events 'started', 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed'
        exceptionFormat "full"
        showStandardStreams = true

        afterSuite { desc, result ->
            if (!desc.parent) { // will match the outermost suite
                failedTest += result.failedTestCount
            }
        }
    }
    include "org/company/project/test/Test2.class"
}
```

I want these 2 tests to run in parallel, currently I use this command to run them `./gradlew cleanTest test1 test2  --info --rerun-tasks` command to run them.

I tried `--parallel`, `--max-workers=3` options nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle doesn't support running tasks inside the same project in parallel, unless you get a [configuration cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/configuration_cache.html) hit, but that is an incubating feature and it might not work for you.

Is there any reason why you don't use forking inside the test task ([docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:test_execution))?

```
test {    
  maxParallelForks = 3
}
```

or for all test tasks

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    maxParallelForks = 3
}
```

Comment: This didn't help, I had tried this before, there was no improvement in execution time